# NHK has a series titled 「きらり！えん旅【たび】」. What does the えん in えん旅 mean?

Tags: usage, meaning

I saw a broadcast named 「えん旅」 on NHK. It's about travel, food, culture. Is it some abbreviation? I don't understand what the 「えん～」 part means.

Comment: [Official page:](http://www.nhk.or.jp/ashita/entabi/) `「えん旅」の“えん”には、応援の“援”、出会った人たちとの“縁”、人々が輪でつながる“円”、旅の締めくくりの旅人によるステージでの公”演” などさまざまな意味を込めています。`

Comment: The answer in English would be very nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We find the following information on their official webpage:

> 「えん旅」の“えん”には、応援の“援”、出会った人たちとの“縁”、人々が輪でつながる“円”、旅の締めくくりの旅人によるステージでの公”演” などさまざまな意味を込めています。

http://www.nhk.or.jp/ashita/entabi/

They are using kana instead of kanji for the first part to leave its meaning open for the viewer. Also, compare this to how some personal (first) names, especially female first names, are kana-only.

As they explain on their webpage, `えん` can be interpreted in different ways, including, but not limited to:

- 援, which stands for 応援【おうえん】, "aid" or "support"
- 縁, referring to the relationship established with the people they meet
- 円, referring to band (or "circle") that connects us all
- 演, which stands for 公演【こうえん】 "public performance"

Another interpretation I can think of is 遠 "far (away", as they are travelling all over the country. Perhaps also as in 遠足【えんそく】.

Comment: Feel free to edit this and add 円 to the list if you can think of a good way to express 輪で繋がる in English.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of 「きらり」 as well? Maybe it is just a name? But in [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%8D%E3%82%89%E3%82%8A) I found some translations, which are not very clear also..